# Python dictionary - find key in next line

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I created dictionary from email body

```
print email body

Application name: dummy.service
Source: host2
Timestamp: 2019-01-23T22:00:01.026Z
Message: LivePnL:in live pricing


Application name: dummy.service
Source: host2
Timestamp: 2019-01-23T22:00:01.016Z
Message: Risk request failed


Application name: dummy.service
Source: host2
Timestamp: 2019-01-23T22:00:00.994Z
Message: Risk request failed
```

if all above is in same line, i can get Application name, Source and Message, but if Source and Message are in new line i can get only Application name

above variable (email body) is input of below function

```
def parse_subject(line):
    info = {}
    segments = line.split(' ')

    info['time'] = segments
    for i in range(2, len(segments)):
        key = ''
        if segments[i] == 'Application Name:':
            key = 'alarm'
        elif segments[i] == 'Source:':
            key = 'job'
        elif segments[i] == 'Message:':
            key = 'machine'
        if key != '':
            i += 1
            info[key] = segments[i]
    return info


 if mail["Subject"].find("Alert for dummy services errors") > 0 :
           body = get_autosys_body(mail)
        for line in body.splitlines():
              if 'Application name' in line:
                job_info = parse_subject(line)
                break
        print (job_info)
```

job info currenly gives me only key from first line

```
{'time': ['Application', 'name:', 'dummy.service']}
```

how to get values after Source and Message ? or how to put lines in email_body into single line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**segments = line.split(' ')**

You need to split the line using multiple delimiters, not just the space (' ') delimiter.

To do this, you need regex.

import re
segments = re.split(' |\n',line)

This should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

you are only calling `parse_subject(line)` `if 'Application name' in line`. Obviously this would only return the line containing the application name. If you would also like to analyze source and message lines I think you would need to take out that if statement. Or you could add more if statements like `if 'Source' in line: parse_subject(line)`

Comment: unless I'm completely misunderstanding the question, which is always possible